# Why people pronounce "penetrative" with two stresses?

Tags: pronunciation

One stress is on "pen". The other on "tra". This seems very unusual to me since I had the impression that most English words are supposed to be pronounced with one stress only.

Comment: Do you mean "stress" instead of "syllable"?  A syllable is (roughly) how many times your chin goes down when you say a word.

Comment: That argument is *indefensible*!

Comment: Your assumption (*most English words are supposed to be pronounced with one stress only*) is [incorrect.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_and_vowel_reduction_in_English#Degrees_of_lexical_stress)

Comment: Hmm. Like bib, I should have said it was /ˌɪnkəˈrɛkt/

Comment: Words having two stresses are quite common in [American English](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/penetrative) and less so in [British English](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/penetrative). But you're quite wrong when you say English words are "supposed to be" pronounced with one stress only ... a long enough word will have [two stresses](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/practicality) even in British English.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a false premise of pronunciation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

English words often have a primary and a secondary stress, especially when they are long (4 syllables or more).  In your example, "pen" has the primary stress, and "tra" has the secondary stress.

Comment: But it sound fine to me to just pronounce it with one stress. Just on "pen"

Comment: Even words of three syllables, if they are accented on the first, routinely get a secondary stress on the third: *cataract* is a fine example. Iambic meter would not be nearly so prevalent in English-language poetry if it were otherwise.

Comment: @BrianDonovan - Hm, I don't stress two syllables with cataract... I think it depends on a variety of things, including it's pronunciation in another language (the one from which it evolved or was borrowed, whether the last syllable changes the function of the word, etc. But I've already said far more than I actually know. I often find the stress is on the antepentultimate syllable, which follows Latin. E.g. escapade /escapism, vertigo/vertiginous, etc.